# Group multiple classes in one item in makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I am working in my first app in c++ 
I came from java and I am using 1 source file per class (actually 2 because of the .h)
Is it a good practice ?

I'm finding my makefile is growing too much each time I have to add a class, that's a new .o file. 
Is there a way to improve it? like compiling a set of .o's into a lib file? or a .o can contain several c++ classes ?

Comment: A .o can contain multiple class definitions. Whether it should or shouldn't is off-topic here

Comment: There's no reason your makefile should need to grow each time you add a file.  If it is you're probably not taking advantage of make's standard facilities for handling this.  But since you don't show us your makefile, we can't provide any help.

Comment: agree with MadScientist. The number of files is a non-issue when you have a proper makefile. Btw C++ doesnt care how many class declarations you put into one file. What is good practice is purely opinion based I am afraid

Answer (score 0):

make contains all kinds of functionality to avoid having to repeat yourself through . For example, in case all your `.cpp` files need to be compiled into a `.o` file, you can use [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html#Pattern-Rules):

```
%.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) $< -c -o $@
```

Here, `$@` contains the target name (the `.o` file), and `$<` the dependency name (the `.cpp` file).

There are other approaches of course. I recommend consulting the manual, in particular the [introduction](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Introduction.html#Introduction) chapter lists various other styles. The whole manual is well written and I recommend reading it in case you are serious about hand-rolling your own makefiles.